# When does a religion become mythology?

Tags: folkloristics, terminology

What is the definition of mythology?

When does a religion become mythology?

Comment: I think religion and mythology should be separated. Adherents to a religion call the stories of religion mythology, meaning they can coexist. Perseus's slaying of Medusa isn't religion, but worshiping Zeus is, if that makes any sense.

Comment: This might be better suited for [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: mythology and religion are more often than not intertwined

Answer (score 6):

On the subject of definition.

**Religion deals with the establishment of certain ideas that prove the existence of superhuman powers in the form of God or Gods.**

It educates the individual with the customs and manners of a particular community or society based on the acceptance of some important faiths and beliefs. Religion is developed and propounded by religious leaders.

When we look at the world today, there are many religions such as Christianity, Buddhism, Islam, Hinduism, etc. All these religions cater towards a singular need of constructing a system of beliefs and getting people to put their faith in that belief.

**In almost all religions, there are mythologies.** Any given religion will dwell in the delineation of its mythological characters. This emphasizes that mythology plays a significant role in religion.

**Mythology is aimed at proving the truths and faiths established by religion.** Mythology aims to establish the faiths put forward by any religion through stories and epics. Mythological characters are created in order to prove the validity of religious statements.

**Religion, on the other hand, depends on its mythology to survive.** This is the most important observation when it comes to the relationship between religion and mythology.

**Mythology deals with characters that reflect the supernatural powers already spoken of by the religion that accompanies that mythology.** 
In short it can be said that mythology confirms and strengthens religious beliefs and truths.

Mythology unlike religion does not deal with the customs and manners of a particular community or society based on the acceptance of faiths and beliefs. It is developed and created for the establishment of truths in their respective religions. **Mythology creates interest in the following of any given religion.**

Answer (score 5):

> What is the definition of mythology?

**Mythology** - a special form of human consciousness, a way to preserve traditions in the ever-changing reality, includes folk tales.

---

> When does a religion become mythology?

Religion becomes mythology when it looses its status of institution of state government and being replaced with another religion.